# Guardar Poligonos de la Api google maps en aps.net mvc en sql server

Tags: html5, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, google-api

Buenas tengo un programa de guardar direcciones, me funciona todo, uso marcadores para las direcciones, mi problema es que necesito que el usuario pueda crear y eliminar los poligonos,
con la ayuda de la documentacion de google logre hacer lo que quiero, pero necesito que se guarde y elimine, ya que cada ves que se refresca la pagina los poligonos desaparecen.

```
//Codigo de poligonos

        const drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
            drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                drawingModes: [
                    
                    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
                    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
                    google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
                ],
            },
            markerOptions: {
                icon: "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png",
            },
            circleOptions: {
                fillColor: "#ffff00",
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 5,
                clickable: false,
                editable: true,
                zIndex: 1,
            },
        });
        drawingManager.setMap(map);
```

Si actualizo la pagina, ese poligono se borra, como podria guardalo, tengo el proyecto en MVC con Entity Framework

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En ese caso, te conviene usar una petición AJAX, cuya URL apunte al método en tu controller que te guarde la información en la base de datos. .NET realiza esta solicitud mapeando el objeto anónimo de JavaScript a un DTO (objeto de transferencia de datos) en C#. Suponiendo un DTOMarcador:

```
public class DtoMarcador(){
     public string lat {get; set;}
     public string lng{get; set;}
}
```

**Nota**: Es importante que sean cadenas de texto, sino puede haber problemas en el mapeo.

Entonces, pasas cada punto del polígono a un array de objetos anónimos con las mismas propiedades lat y lng (**tienen que llamarse igual**) y eso lo pasas a través de la petición AJAX con la instrucción

```
data: JSON.stringify(<ArrayObjetosAnonimos>)
```

Entonces, la petición quedaría:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(<ArrayObjetosAnonimos>),
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "<TU_SERVIDOR>/TU_CONTROLLER/TU_METODO",
            success: function (respuesta) {

            },
            error: function (respuesta) {

            }
        })
```

A partir de entonces, ya tienes toda la información en tu controlador